# why the right button can't on the right of parent like left button on the left of parent

Tags: android, layout-gravity

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="left" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I know I can also use Relativelayout and set alignparentRight=true,to let the right button on the right of this parent,But I just want to know,if I use a LinearLayout,how can I make the right button on the right of it's parent? any help thanks

Comment: yes,but it not work. and I really want to know why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have only three or two child you can use `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`. But if you want to use `LinearLayout` do like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="left" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using a `FrameLayout` as parent

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="left" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="right" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Why `layout_gravity="right"` is not working for *Horizontal LinearLayout* [explained here](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.in/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html)

For a *horizontal Linear Layout* the following values make sense:

- top
- center
- bottom

> That is because the children of a horizontal Linear Layout are layed
>   out horizontally one after the other. Only thing can be controlled
>   using the android:layout_gravity is how a child view is positioned
>   vertically.

For a *vertical Linear Layout* the following values make sense:

- left
- center
- right

> That is because the children of a vertical Linear Layout are layed out
>   vertically one below the other. Only thing can be controlled using the
>   android:layout_gravity is how a child view is positioned horizontally.

Comment: thanks,and If I use LinearLayout like you say,without the Layout_gravity property it also work because the layout_weight.but thank you

Comment: in `LinearLayout` doesn't need `layout_gravity` only `layout_weight` is required

Comment: yeah,but my question is ,if I have two button in a horizontal LinearLayout(android:layout_width="match_parent") ,one's layout_gravity="left",another is layout_gravity="right",why the right button can't on the right of it's parent. I was very very confused this.

Comment: for ur requirement use `Framelayout` why `layout_gravity` is not working [explained here.](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.in/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html) Please read that.

Answer (score 0):

Put the center button in a RelativeLayout with weight 1 so that the center layout takes the whole area.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left" />
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For two buttons

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left" />
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="right" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you,it works. but If I have only two child in a LinearLayout ,how to make them,one on the left of the parent,another on the right of the parent. how can I set the layout_gravity ?

Comment: and If I set the RelativeLayout gone ,it just not work

Comment: For 2 buttons you can remove the third button and put the android:gravity="right" on the RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Why not use weights,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="left" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And if you have two buttons

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="left" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note**: Implementing this way involves many layouts to be added and will cause problems when the app is pretty heavy. Its always recommended to use the Relative Layout.

Comment: thanks,but  I was also confused how to use the layout_gravity? why I set layout_gravity="right" on the right button ,but it not works.

Comment: Bad Idea. We shouldn't use too many layouts if single can do the job. Number of layouts affect application performance and even cause crashes if depth is too much. Use relative layout instead. Any specific requirement to use linear layout??

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Thanks for pointing that out. I will add a note on my answer. But the answer was so to show the OP the workaround. The OP already knew to implement using the Relative Layout.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked @lightman1988 if he/she has any specific thing in mind which forces him/her to use linear layout. :)

Comment: Thanks,I just want know why layout_weight="right" didn't work.if I want right button on the right of button.If I have one child,It works,but why two or more can't

Comment: @lightman1988 That is the nature of a **horizontal** Linear Layout. To learn more have a quick look at these tutorials. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxfYeAUd238&index=47&list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyCGSSD_nuPAmXDSR_FU0RR

Comment: thank you very much,but what is the nature of a horizontal LinearLayout,what do you mean

Comment: `layout_gravity` has certain limitations for both the orientations of the Linear Layout. Kindly check the link I posted in my earlier comment. You have a clear explanation there.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 Relative layout instead of 
 linear layout.
```

and use layout_alignParentRight to make it right of the parent.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="left" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It seems he already knew that method. He just wanted to try the same with Linear Layout. Kindly read the question fully!

Comment: thanks,I know this. But I just want to know,if I use a LinearLayout,how can I make the right button on the right of it's parent?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this if you don't want potential overlapping cause by `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and still wanna use `wrap_content` width which you can't if you align views properly in `RelativeLayout` to avoid overlapping:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="left" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="center" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This method is pretty common and is used by (at least last time i checked it was) `AlertDialog` in the appcompat lib